# We have 30,000 questions!

Tags: discussion

At the time of typing this we have exactly 30,000 questions!

That's a lot of effort by both askers and answerers. Well done to everybody concerned! :-)

Comment: Cool! That's only 1,416 more questions for a nice, big, round number!

Comment: Yay! @EmilioPisanty I task you with asking a question worth .9265358979(...) questions :P

Comment: Proud to have contributed 0.4% to this.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty please check your math.  By my calculations we're 2,768 short of a nice round number :-)

Comment: @BrandonEnright I thought of that, but then what's so special about 15? We're really 35,536 questions away from a *properly* round number.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty 1000[...]000 is a nice number in any base regardless of the number of zeros.  $\pi$ is a mess in every base (well except base-$\pi$).

Comment: @BrandonEnright Fourier series in base $\pi$ would be awesome. But that's about it.

Comment: I'm sure you rocked almost half of it! :P

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.